# When should I use which command to run Cypher query via java (neo4j)?

Tags: java, neo4j, cypher

It seems that there are different command to run Cypher query on Java: 
executionEngine.execute("cyper command"), session.run("cyper command"), statement.executeQuery("cypher command")  (So far I could find nothing else)
(The first command comes from: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/neo4j/neo4j_cypher_api_example.htm;
the last two commands come from: https://neo4j.com/developer/java/#_the_example_project)

I thought that session.run("cyper command") should be used when there is no result to be return such as when a csv files is imported. However, this proves me wrong: [How to load CSV file with cypher in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34745005/how-to-load-csv-file-with-cypher-in-java/34748177)

So when should I use which? Or can they be run interchangeably?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how you use Neo4j.
If you use it embedded, then you have access to the core API such as ExecutionEngine. [This](https://neo4j.com/docs/java-reference/current/#tutorials-java-embedded) provides more information on how to use Neo4j in embedded mode.

If you run a Neo4j Server, then you have many options, one of which is to use the Bolt driver (session.run etc.). See the [Drivers section](https://info.neo4j.com/WBP-PDF-Documentation.html?doc=neo4j-developer-manual-3.1-java&_ga=1.25084926.576249236.1453208740) for how to use this.

Then, there are frameworks such as Neo4j OGM and SDN providing convenient ways to access Neo4j. See https://neo4j.com/developer/java/

Comment: Do you know when should I use embedded and when should I use driver?

Comment: If you want to run neo4j in the same jvm as your application, then embedded is the way to go

Comment: How could it be possible to run neo4j in a different jvm from the java application which is running it? (Sorry I am really new to this.)

Comment: Neo4j can run in server mode- that's when you connect to it via your application via a driver for example. Similar to applications connecting to remote databases using jdbc