# Why don't the two import line in java regarding cypher and neo4j work?

Tags: java, neo4j, cypher

In https://www.tutorialspoint.com/neo4j/neo4j_cypher_api_example.htm and [How to load CSV file with cypher in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34745005/how-to-load-csv-file-with-cypher-in-java/34748177), there are always these two import lines:

```
import org.neo4j.cypher.javacompat.ExecutionEngine;
import org.neo4j.cypher.javacompat.ExecutionResult;
```

However, there are errors when I tried to import these two items. For  the class ExecutionEngine, it seems I could import from org.neo4j.cypher.internal or org.neo4j.cypher.internal.javacompat, which one should I import (given I did nothing wrong so that I could not import from org.neo4j.cypher.javacompat)?

What is a reason why I could not import from org.neo4j.cypher.javacompat?

The relevant dependency of the driver in maven repository I am using:

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>org.neo4j.driver</groupId>
      <artifactId>neo4j-java-driver</artifactId>
      <version>1.2.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your dependency is incorrect- org.neo4j.cypher.javacompat does not belong to the Neo4j Java Driver, rather:

```
 <dependency>
   <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
   <artifactId>neo4j</artifactId>
   <version>${neo.version}</version>
  </dependency>
```

See https://neo4j.com/docs/java-reference/current/#_add_neo4j_as_a_dependency for more info

Comment: I have already had the dependency you described in my pom.xml
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
   <artifactId>neo4j</artifactId>
   <version>3.1.2</version>
  </dependency>   
I also have added neo4j enterprise as dependency, but it does not work either: (same error. )    
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
   <artifactId>neo4j-enterprise</artifactId>
   <version>3.1.1</version>
  </dependency>

Comment: There are two ExecutionEngine classes, one in package org.neo4j.cypher.javacompat and one in org.neo4j.cypher. Typically you should use the first one in Neo4j <= 2.1.x.

In Neo4j 2.2 ExecutionEngine is deprecated. Instead use the two execute methods in GraphDatabaseService.